# Modifying a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string in python

```
 name="My name is John"
```

I want to replace name with:

```
 name ="My name is JohnSmith"
```

can anyone help??

Comment: Note that you cannot modify a string in Python, strings are immutable.  You can bind `name` to an *entirely different* string, which new string has the contents you desire.

Comment: If you want to replace name with different string, you have already done so in your example. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a string in python as they are immutable, so modifying a string always results a new string.

For your example you can use:

String concatenation:

```
>>> name = "My name is John"
>>> name += "Smith"       #equivalent to name = name + "Smith"
>>> name
'My name is JohnSmith'
```

or string formatting:

```
>>> name = "My name is John"
>>> name = "{0}{1}".format(name,"Smith")
>>> name
'My name is JohnSmith'
```

For concatenating a list of many items prefer [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) :

```
>>> name="My name is John"
>>> name = "".join((name,"Smith","foo","bar","spam"))
>>> name
'My name is JohnSmithfoobarspam'
```

Comment: You should rephrase it, "For concatenating a list of many items", prefer `str.join`, for 2 items, `"".join((x, y))` is just an ugly version of `x + y`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> name[:11] + 'John Smith'
'My name is John Smith'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "My name is John"
str = str.replace("John","JohnSmith")
```

Comment: don't call your string `str`, `str` is a builtin

Comment: yeah, i should'nt be, bt it worked.

Comment: Now try `print str(1)`

Comment: hmm, it gives same error for any other variable used in place of str.
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable